# SQL Server variable after a sub query in select

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a query like below. My concern is, this query doesn't work until I put something after the subquery. I never came across such things in SQL. My lead asked me to put a variable after the last closing bracket and I am afraid why and curious why should we have a variable. I use SQL Server 2005.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM  
    (SELECT ID 
     FROM NAMES N 
     LEFT JOIN PEOPLE P ON N.ID = P.ID 
     WHERE P.NAME = @name
     GROUP BY ID)
```

This one below works like a charm. I don't understand why should be put something after the bracket.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM   
    (SELECT ID 
     FROM NAMES N 
     LEFT JOIN PEOPLE P ON N.ID = P.ID 
     WHERE P.NAME = @name
     GROUP BY ID) Temp
```

Comment: This is not variable, but subquery's alias. Looks like it is required by server you use at this moment. When your outer query is a bit more complex and have joins you need the alias to refer the columns rerurned by the subquery.

Comment: @fifonik: Even an alias for count(*) doesn't help here.   SELECT COUNT(*) As Count  FROM  (SELECT ID FROM NAMES N LEFT JOIN PEOPLE P 
                                ON N.ID = P.ID WHERE P.NAME = name
                                  GROUP BY ID)

Comment: the `Temp` in your second query is not a `variable`. It is called `alias`. You need to give an `alias` to the `derived table`

Comment: @Squirrel: Nice name lol...well yes my lead told me that and said it is just naming a subquery result....It only works with that :(

Answer (score 0):

Putting an alias **for the subquery** may not seem very useful (even to me) but the SQL standard says there should be one. Truly, there is no other reason.

That being said, do you want to do one of the following?

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(*) 
FROM NAMES N LEFT JOIN PEOPLE P 
                            ON N.ID = P.ID
WHERE P.NAME = @name
GROUP BY ID
```

Or

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM NAMES N LEFT JOIN PEOPLE P 
                            ON N.ID = P.ID
WHERE P.NAME = @name
```

Edit: Seeing your comment and as @GordonLinoff mentionned, you can try the following query too; no join.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM PEOPLE
WHERE NAME = @name
```

Note that the result of it will be the same **only** if either Names.id or People.id are unique. If neither of the 2 fields are, then the count will be different.

Comment: Join is expensive and I dont understand your query

Comment: The join comes from you ... Anyway, your question was about giving a alias to the sub-query, right? My answer is: it is because of SQL standard + in your case, there was no need to do a sub-query (= no need to bother with the alias).

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to write this is

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT P.ID)
FROM PEOPLE P
WHERE P.NAME = @name;
```

Your `LEFT JOIN` is being turned into an `INNER JOIN` by the `WHERE` clause anyway (there has to be a match).  Then, the `JOIN` is not necessary, because you are counting `ID`, which is used for the `JOIN`.  You can just count the matching ids in `PEOPLE`.  `ID` cannot be `NULL` because it is used for the `JOIN`.

If `ID` is unique in `PEOPLE`, then:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM PEOPLE P
WHERE P.NAME = @name;
```

Comment: Join is always expensive and I dont understand your query :(

Comment: my question is why we need the alias

Comment: @Learner . . . `JOIN` is not always expensive.  I don't understand what is difficult about this query.  And aliases for subqueries in the `FROM` clause are required in many but not all databases.  That is simply the syntax of SQL.